# .Net VB MD5 hash not encoding to same value on identical web sites

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hash, md5

I inherited a VB ASP.NET website that I am trying to update. I made a duplicate of the website on the same server, pointing to the same backend SQL Server database. However, when any user tries to login the **md5Hasher.ComputeHash** function is returning a hash that is different from the original site and all logins fail.

In the original code the passwork is salted, then **UTF8 encoded** before being passed to the MD5Hasher. To further complicate things, the database field for the password is NVarchar but the password is passed as a Binary parameter.

Here is the section of code(Not my code!):

```
Dim hashedDataBytes As Byte()
Dim encoder As New UTF8Encoding()
Dim md5Hasher As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
Dim paramPwd As SqlParameter

hashedDataBytes = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(txtPassword.Text + "%#$" + txtlogin.Text + "R$&#d@EdNdH(A#r%)*@e#"))

paramPwd = New SqlParameter("Password", SqlDbType.Binary, 16)
paramPwd.Value = hashedDataBytes
myConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
sql = "Select * FROM tbl_clients WHERE ClientUserID = @UserID And ClientPassword = @Password"
Dim cmdSql As New SqlCommand(sql, myConnection)
```

This returns 0 records, the same code running on the original website with the same backend database works. Doing an SQL Track shows that different values are being passed as the password parameter. For some reason, the MD5 hash function is returning a different value given the same input string.
(could forcing the parameter to binary be the cause?)

Comment: so hashedDataBytes is different between the two environment? if yes, remove the code about the sql since it is unrelated and take 50% of the code snippet

Comment: The problem is that due to the binary parameter I can't tell if the hash function is returning a value that is different from the one in the database is the one in the database is unreadable.

Comment: Can you add breakpoints in each to determine where the difference is occurring?

Comment: I admit this isn't likely to be the cause, but it's worth noting that logging in as "JohnSmith" could fail while the same password with "johnsmith" succeeds. The way this is written, the login (username) used in the hash is case-sensitive. It's not something you can change in the code without recomputing all the hashes in the database, but just make sure the case of the login you're attempting exactly matches the case of the login in the db.

Comment: (Also, after you've resolved this issue, I'd heartily recommend upgrading from MD5, as that offers little to no security against hackers. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right )

Comment: @lamelemon I don't have access to the old website for debugging, I can only use SQL tracing.@A.Franklin I am well aware of the issues around MD5, but changing the hash would require all users to reset their passwords.

Comment: @RobertMcCabe Not necessarily! You could wrap the MD5 hashing in PDKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt. Basically, create a new db column ("StrongHashedPassword") and set all values to the PDKDF2-hashed value of the MD5 column. Add an intermediate line of code (right after `hashedDataBytes = ...`, so you *are* still doing the MD5 hashing) to do the PDKDF2 hashing, and compare that to the value of the new db column. Test the crap out of it, then delete the MD5 column. Boom, transparent to users, the security hole is gone!

Comment: can you change the code so it would output hashedDataBytes to a file or whatever in a HEX format (don't forget to undo the change when your done...)

Comment: @fredou I use NLog to get the values at each step, but the cast to Binary in the parameter prevents me from getting a value I can compare to what is in the database.